# UK visitor visa proof of funds

Tags: visas, uk, proof-provenance-of-funds

I lent $5K AUD to a person close to me around 5 months back and he is repaying me by transferring me the money into my account. I'll be applying for a UK visa next month; would this look like fund parking?

I am able to provide transfer receipts showing that money went from my account 5 months ago, and I can also provide his receipt of returning the money.

I can also show 1 year's bank statements account from two of my savings accounts and, if they investigate and reconcile in detail, they will be able to see that money left my account and returned.

I am just concerned that if it's seen as fund parking, they would refuse my visa.

Comment: As long as you document this transfer on your application and besides that one transfer your account shows healthy signs you should be fine.

Comment: I don't think this will be seen as fund parking. You are showing an interrelation between your accounts and even linkage to someone else's account. I don't know whether you should preemptively explain it explicitly in your application package.

Comment: If you are concerned enough about it to ask the question, then you should definitely think about documenting it in your application - no more than a paragraph referring to the two transactions with an explanation as to their association and meaning.

Comment: Of course it looks like funds parking so you will have to take care explaining it to them.